# Calling a method from a vue bootstrap button stops page rendering

Tags: c#, api, vue.js, asp.net-web-api, methods

This is the button in my HTML

```
<b-button variant="danger" id="toggle-btn" @click="delete">Delete</b-button>
```

If I take the call to the method out (@click="delete) my page renders, if I leave it there then nothing renders to the screen. but there are also no errors in the console.

This is where I export my methods and declare the delete method:

```
methods: {
      showModal() {
        this.$refs['my-modal'].show()
      },
      hideModal() {
        this.$refs['my-modal'].hide()
      },
      toggleModal() {
        // We pass the ID of the button that we want to return focus to
        // when the modal has hidden
        this.$refs['my-modal'].toggle('#toggle-btn')
      },
      delete() {
        fetch('https://localhost:44328/api/Skill/' + this.$route.params.id, {
        method: 'delete'
      })
      }
    }
```

I've searched far and wide and can't find an answer. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's happening to your errors but I made a quick fiddle based on your code and I get this error in the console

`avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "delete" 
 Raw expression: @click="delete"`

I suggest you change your method name to a non-js keyword, perhaps deleteSkill.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    delete() {
      console.log("Delete");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="delete">DELETE</button>
</div>
```